# Change permission of file owned by root-user without using sudo

Tags: linux, root, sudo, chmod, linux-capabilities

I have a file owned by "root" and script owned by "non-root" user. I'm trying to change permission of "root" owned file using "non-root" script and getting below error:

```
$ cat root_file
echo "HELLO WORLD"

$ cat non_root_script
chmod 777 root_file.txt

$ ./non_root_script
chmod: changing permissions of 'abc.txt': Operation not permitted
```

I tried adding capabilities to the non_root_script but I'm still getting same error.

```
$ sudo setcap CAP_FOWNER+ep non_root_script
$ ./non_root_script
chmod: changing permissions of 'abc.txt': Operation not permitted
```

Are there any other capabilities that I need to provide, if so please suggest. Also I don't want to use "sudo chmod".

Answer (score 0):

GNU/Linux strongly discourages AT_SECURE transitions (which includes file system capabilities) on shell scripts:

- [Allow setuid on shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/241115)

You could work around that using a small C program, but what you are trying to do could still very insecure, even if you change the path to `root_file.txt` to an absolute path due to file system race conditions.  Very permissive file modes like `777` also lead to security issues.  I suggest to investigate other solutions to your original problems.